# Link between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript

I have 2 big arrays of Data. The datas of the first array contains some references to elements of the second array. But this references are initialy null and we only have the id of the element (the Guid not the index in the array).

Minimised example  :

```
        var A = [{
            idA: "113b9035-5f99-40c6-83cc-01e4bbf306e1",
            idB: "fccee5fb-c6ce-4bdf-b9ae-31d15df9c97d",
            B: null
        },
        ...
        ];
        var B = [{
            idB: "fccee5fb-c6ce-4bdf-b9ae-31d15df9c97d"
        },
        ...
        ];
```

I want to put B on A.B (reasons are explained later).

I created a method to do that :

```
    lierDonnees = function<TA,TB> (
        listeDestination: TA[],
        idDestination: string,
        lienDestination: string,
        listeSource: TB[],
        idSource: string ): void {
        listeDestination.forEach(( itemDestination: TA ) => {
            var result = $.grep( listeSource, function ( itemSource: TB ) {
                return itemSource[idSource] === itemDestination[idDestination];
            });
            if ( result.length > 0 ) {
                itemDestination[lienDestination] = result[0];
            }
        });
    };
```

The complexity of this function is :
**(listeDestination.length) * (listeSource.length)**

So let's say **N²**.

My question is : do you see a faster way ?

Now let's talk about the "**Why**".

I have a REST web service (ASP.NET WebApi) which offers this data. As I have way more "A" than "B", i put A.B to null before sending the datas (to avoid redondancies because a lot of A has the same B). And I also want to be able to access to A only (without B). So A and B are in differents Web API controllers.

In conclusion : To get datas faster, i download them unlinked and separatly (so I can prioritize which data i want first). I only keep ids. So my Front-End app' has to do the job of linking datas.

**Edit : Tarh solution**

Using a map between idB and B. Complexity : **2N** !

```
    lierDonnees = function <TA, TB>(
        listeDestination: TA[],
        idDestination: string,
        lienDestination: string,
        listeSource: TB[],
        idSource: string ): void {

        var mapIdSourceItemSource: any = {};
        var i: number;
        for ( i = 0; i < listeSource.length; ++i )
            mapIdSourceItemSource[listeSource[i][idSource]] = listeSource[i];

        var itemDestination, itemSource;
        for ( i = 0; i < listeDestination.length; ++i ) {
            itemDestination = listeDestination[i];
            itemSource = mapIdSourceItemSource[itemDestination[idDestination]];
            if ( itemSource ) {
                itemDestination[lienDestination] = itemSource;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object as a map:

```
// First, fill bMap
var bMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < B.length; ++i)
    bMap[B[i].idB] = B[i];
// Then, use it
var a, b;
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
    a = A[i];
    b = bMap[a.idB]
    if (b) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```